# How is std::vector<bool> declared/defined?

Tags: c++, oop, templates, vector, std

In various online resources, I've read that `std::vector<bool>` has custom behaviors that are completely different from other types of std::vectors.

Specifically, it condenses the vector such that each index represents a single bit, rather than the standard bool type (32-bits or however big it is).

My question is, how was std::vector defined to achieve this?
Can you override the existing behavior of a template class, but only for specific template parameters? (bool, in this case)
Is this achieved ***without*** the need to define an entire derived class and override/redefine the behavior using inheritance?

Comment: This is known as *specialization*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can you override the existing behavior of a template class, but only for specific template parameters?

Yes. This is known as *specialization*, and is one of the fundamental building blocks of template metaprogramming.

`std::vector` is *partially specialized* for the case where the first template parameter is `bool`, something like this:

```
namespace std {
    template<class T, class Alloc = std::allocator<T>>
    class vector {
        // normal vector stuff
    };

    template<class Alloc>
    class vector<bool, Alloc> {
        // special code for bools
    };
}
```

You can also fully specialize a class template. For instance:

```
struct Bar;

template<class T>
struct Foo {
     // standard stuff
};

template <>
struct Foo<Bar> {
     // special stuff in case T is Bar
};
```

This can be used in many interesting ways. For example, you can write a type that detects if another type is a `std::vector`:

```
template<class T>
struct is_vector {
    static const bool value = false;
};

template<class T, class A>
struct is_vector<std::vector<T, A>> {
   static const bool value = true;
};
```

Comment: Interesting ... thanks for the detailed response. In the vector specialization you summarized, would there be any purpose in providing the default value for the Alloc parameter? e.g. template<class Alloc = std::allocator<bool>>

Comment: @Giffyguy No, partial specializations can't have default arguments